# Monte Carlo Method in R

Tags: r, montecarlo

I'm trying to learn R. I'm trying to write a program which calculates (approximately) pi.
[Read About the method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)

My code is not working right now!

```
f <- 0
s <- 0
range <- 10000
for (i in (1:range)) {
    v <- sample(1:range, 1)/range
    n <- sample(1:range, 1)/range

    if ( sqrt (v*v + n*n) <= 1) {
        f <- f + 1
    } else if ( v <=1 && n <= 1) {
        s <- s+1
    }
}

print ( f/s )
```

Comment: In the given code `f` falls inside the circle and `s` falls _outside_ the circle due to `else if` statement. Therefore, the results for `f/s` seems to be (pi/4)/(1-pi/4) = 3.6597... If you replace `else if` with just `if`, then the result is (pi/4)/1, and after multiplying by four you get 4*(pi/4) = pi.

Comment: ... actually, you can delete `if( v <= 1 && n <= 1)`, too, because `sample(1:range, 1)/range` is always between `1/range` and 1. To conform to the Wikipedia method, you'll need `sample(0:range, 1)/range`, even though in practice (big values of `range`) it won't matter too much

Comment: Finally, your code is fine for first steps in R, but note that R is not like C or Java in that you need loops for everything. Most of the time you can modify whole vectors at once, which is faster and, more importantly, shorter (less bugs).@mickey's solution shows that. For example, he is comparing a whole numeric vector to 1 which gives a logical vector. `sum` then just counts the `TRUE`s in that vector. Over time, I'd recommend that you work your way through the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For example, you'd burn in Circle 3 ("Failing to vectorize") ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an improved version of your code

```
range = 100000
v = runif(range)
n = runif(range)
f = sum(sqrt(v^2 + n^2) <= 1)

print(4 * f / range)
```

You should use `runif` to get samples from a uniform instead of `sample(...) / range`.

The `s` is unnecessary since what you're doing is counting the number of times, `f`, that your random point `(v,n)` is within the circle in that quadrant, divided by the number of attempted draws, which would just be `range` in your case.

You need to multiply by `4` since `f / range` approximates the area of one-quarter of the unit circle.